# Rails ActiveAdmin Routing new Resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

I'm just starting out with Rails and I decided to try out ActiveAdmin last night. I was able to register a new resource name 'Pages' in my ActiveAdmin app, but there's one thing I can't figure out how to customize with it.

I create a new Page with ActiveAdmin, but it's published within the admin/.. path.
(e.g. mydomain/admin/page/1)

How do I change the routing so the page can be viewed at mydomain/page/1?
Are you able to change the routing of existing resources in ActiveAdmin?

I'm very new at Rails so I assume this is a pretty easy fix. I plan to run through some more tutorials/books so I can better understand routing.

Comment: why would you need that?

Comment: I was thinking of modifying this as some kind of CMS. I want to create published Pages that can be viewed outside of the admin/ path. That make sense? Just tinkering with this and trying to see what it can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the default `admin` namespace.

To do so you have to go to `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` file and find the following configuration:

```
  # Default:
  # config.default_namespace = :admin
```

Uncomment the line and set the `default_namespace` to whatever you need.

However, if you need to turn off the namespace at all, you will have to set the `default_namespace` to `false`:

```
config.default_namespace = false
```

This will allow you to run the AA from the root.

By doing so be aware of changes in routes:

if changed the namespace to `hello`, the `admin_games_path` becomes `hello_games_path`;

if changed to no namespace, use normal routes: `admin_games_path` becomes `games_path`.

Comment: Thanks. That seems to apply to everything in AA. How would I restrict it to only the View of the custom Page resource I create?

So when I click the View button on a Page (ID#1) item from within my Admin interface, the page will be viewed at mydomain/page/1

Comment: @mrtonyb `get 'desired_path', to: 'admin/controller#action'`